# C linkage for function pointer passed to C library

Tags: c++, c, signals, glibc, linkage

My case is pretty simple: I want my C++ program to deal with Unix signals. To do so, glibc provides a function in signal.h called `sigaction`, which expects to receive a function pointer as its second argument.

```
extern "C"
{
void uponSignal(int);
}

void uponSignal(int)
{
    // set some flag to quit the program
}

static
void installSignalHandler()
{
    // initialize the signal handler
    static struct sigaction sighandler;
    memset( &sighandler, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction) );
    sighandler.sa_handler = uponSignal;

    // install it
    sigaction( SIGINT, &sighandler, nullptr );
}
```

My question is: is the `extern "C"` linkage specifier necessary?

Bonus question: can uponSignal be declared `static`?

Comment: Some compilers will simply refuse to compile it if you remove `extern "C"` because the second argument to sigaction has the wrong type. It is a bug in many compilers that they don't consider linkage part of the function type.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is: is the `extern "C"` linkage specifier necessary?

For maximum portability, yes; the C++ standard only guarantees interoperability with C via functions declared `extern "C"`.

Practically, no; most sensible ABIs (including the GNU ABI used by glibc) will use the same calling convention for C and  C++ non-member (and static member) functions, so that `extern "C"` is only needed to share the function name between languages.

> Bonus question: can `uponSignal` be declared static?

Yes. External linkage is only needed to access the function by name from other translation units; it's not necessary to call the function via a function pointer.

Comment: Would you have a quote to back “The C++ standard only  guarantees interoperability with C via function declared extern "C" ”?

Comment: @qdii: Not really; there's nothing that explicitly says there's no guarantee, just nothing that provides that guarantee. 7.5/1 specifies that "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical", and has a note indicating that "a particular language linkage may be associated with [...] a particular calling convention, etc."

Answer (score 3):

`extern C` is only necessary if you export your symbols from your binary or import them from another binary (typically in both cases, a shared library), in order to avoid name mangling.

Here this is not the case, you're not linking `uponSignal` across various binaries so you don't need `extern C`. All you're doing is pass your function's address to `sigaction` from a function that already knows `uponSignal`'s address since they are (apparently) part of the same translation unit, or at the very least of the same binary.

> Bonus question: can `uponSignal` be declared `static`?

Sure if you want. `uponSignal` doesn't need external linkage anyway.

Comment: Actually, I was more worried about **calling conventions** than name mangling.

Comment: You shouldn't. ;) Even though calling conventions are implementation-specific (ie. outside the scope of the standard), I've never seen a compiler that didn't make the calling convention part of the function signature so that the compiler will warn you if there ever is a mismatch (which seldom happens anyway).