# How to declare a function pointer that has C linkage?

Tags: c++

I've been using C++ code like this for years

```
void(*ptr)(int) = &func;
```

and not until today did I notice the function pointer has C++ linkage. I knew it's perfectly okay to use a pointer declared like this to receive a function from a C library, but I'm still curious. Is there an official way to declare a function pointer that has C linkage in C++? I've tried

```
extern "C" void(*ptr)(int);
```

but, of course, it doesn't work. The closest I can get is

```
#include <cstdio>
extern "C" int func(void) { return 42; }

extern "C" typedef int ptr_t(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ptr_t *ptr = &func;
    std::printf("%d\n", (*ptr)());
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm not sure whether `ptr` has C linkage. Plus, `extern "C"` seemingly cannot be move into any scope except the global one. So, the question is: Is there a C++ syntax than declares a variable with language linkage in local scope? So, we can do something like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern "C" ptr_t *ptr = &func;
    std::printf("%d\n", (*ptr)());
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `extern "C" { void (*ptr)(int); }` as well? (In global scope. For local variables, it shouldn't be an issue. The `extern "C"` is about name mangling (I always thought) which is regardless for local variables.)

Comment: FYI: [SO: C linkage for function pointer passed to C library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16520951/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff Just tried it and g++ said "error: expected unqualified-id before string constant". The code cannot be move into local scope. It seems that `extern` can only be in global scope, I'm not sure though.

Comment: It's in fact possible to make an `extern` declaration in a function body: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1569bec2c465e3c3). But, of course, this has nothing to do with `extern "C"`. This is what the compiler expects to read - hence the _"error: expected unqualified-id before string constant"_

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the link and the `extern` example. :)